# How to get Outlook to display smart curly quotes in email newsletter

Tags: email, outlook

I'm designing an email newsletter. When I test it in Outlook 2000, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013, curly, smart, typographers quotes (both single and double) are displayed as straight quote marks. I've coded the quote marks as

```
&ldquo; and &rdquo; and &lsquo; and &rsquo;
```

I'm using charset=utf-8

I'm assuming that Outlook doesn't use utf-8 ?

Comment: Which part of this was google unable to help with?

Comment: Hi. I've Google several variations of "outlook displays curly quotes as straight quotes in email newsletter" but no joy.

Comment: I'm going to try     For “ Left double quotes: Use &#8220;
    For ” Left double quotes: Use &#8221;
    For ’ Apostrophe: Use &#8217;

Comment: How about 'outlook smart quotes', which gets you https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-017963a0-bc5f-486b-9c9d-0ec511a8fb8f

Comment: I'm designing an email newsletter. Recipients using Outlook see straight quotes rather than smart quotes. My question is how to get Outlook to display proper curly, smart quotes.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I believe the answer is set up the app that you are using to send out your emails, so that it is sending them as UTF-8. For example I am using Direct Mail and have to manually select 'Text Encoding' to 'Unicode UTF-8'. I've used Litmus to test my email and this has resolved the problem.